# Memory Leak in Using Python API PyArray_SimpleNewFromData

Tags: python, c++, memory-leaks, cython, valgrind

I am not able to figure out cause of memory leak in the following code; Valgrind is reporting memory in on executing the following function. This might be happening due to my lack of understanding of Py_INCREF and Py_DECREF macros.

Here the c++ code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>
#include "numpy/arrayobject.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    PyObject *pName = NULL;
    PyObject *pModule = NULL;
    PyObject *pFunc = NULL;
    PyObject *pArgs = NULL;
    PyObject *pValue = NULL;
    PyObject *vec = NULL;
    PyObject *vec1 = NULL;

    const char* script = "TestScript";
    const char* function = "test";

    Py_Initialize();
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString(script);
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

    // Deleting memory for object pName
    Py_DECREF(pName);

    import_array1(-1);

    if (pModule != NULL) {
        pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, function);

        if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
            // define a vector
            double* v = new double[5];
            v[0] = 1.0;
            v[1] = 2.0;
            v[2] = 3.0;             
            v[3] = 4.0;             
            v[4] = 5.0;

            double* v1 = new double[5];
            v1[0] = 1.0;
            v1[1] = 2.0;
            v1[2] = 3.0;                
            v1[3] = 4.0;                
            v1[4] = 5.0;

            npy_intp vdim[] = { 5 };

            vec = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, vdim, (int)PyArray_DOUBLE, (void*)v);
            vec1 = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, vdim, (int)PyArray_DOUBLE, (void*)v1);

            pArgs = PyTuple_New(2);
            Py_INCREF(vec); // If I don't do this, I get segfault in Py_Finalize**
            Py_INCREF(vec1); // If I don't do this, I get segfault in Py_Finalize**

            PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, vec);
            PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, vec1);


            pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);

            Py_DECREF(pArgs);
            Py_XDECREF(vec);
            Py_XDECREF(vec1);

            delete [] v;
            delete [] v1;

            if (pValue != NULL) {
                printf("Result of call: %f\n", PyFloat_AsDouble(pValue));
                Py_DECREF(pValue);
            }

            Py_DECREF(pFunc);
        } else {
            if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
                PyErr_Print();
                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find function \"%s\"\n", function);
            }
        }
        Py_DECREF(pModule);
    } else {
        PyErr_Print();
        return 1;
    }

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Here the the Python function

```
def test(a, b):
    print("Python::test")
    print(a)
    print(b)

    return 1
```

Here the summary of Valgrind report.

```
==81480== 154,839 bytes in 81 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1,258 of 1,259
==81480==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==81480==    by 0x4ED9777: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0)
==81480==    by 0x4EA81D8: PyUnicode_New (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0)
==81480==    by 0x4EABFDC: _PyUnicode_FromASCII (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0)
==81480==    by 0x4FA073C: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0)
==81480==    by 0x4EE8038: PyCFunction_Call (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0)
==81480==    by 0x4FF41B4: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0)
==81480==    by 0x4FF4638: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0)
==81480==    by 0x5084CAB: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0)
==81480==    by 0x5084D82: PyEval_EvalCodeEx (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0)
==81480==    by 0x4FEC9CA: PyEval_EvalCode (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0)
==81480==    by 0x4FF967C: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0)
==81480==


> ==55233== 
> ==55233== 
> ==55233== HEAP SUMMARY:
> ==55233==     in use at exit: 2,642,149 bytes in 4,750 blocks
> ==55233==   total heap usage: 42,001 allocs, 37,251 frees, 34,675,848 bytes allocated
> ==55233== 
> ==55233== LEAK SUMMARY:
> ==55233==    definitely lost: 157,656 bytes in 85 blocks
> ==55233==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==55233==      possibly lost: 158,663 bytes in 90 blocks
> ==55233==    still reachable: 2,325,830 bytes in 4,575 blocks
> ==55233==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==55233== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
> ==55233== 
> ==55233== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
> ==55233== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
> ==55233== ERROR SUMMARY: 3460 errors from 123 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: I am not sure to look at with that option. I have updated Valgrind log in the problem description above.

Comment: It looks like something inside of the python’s shared library (possibly when loading?). But this is not the only leak, isn’t it? Did you build your stuff in debug?

Comment: On further debugging, I realized that leak is due to  "import_array1(-1)" call? Not sure how to fix it. This call is necessary to use numpy array in C.

Comment: Then this is probably `PyArray_API`, don't think you could (or should) do something about it.

Comment: Looks like it is not a leak. Rather, the leak is reported due to a statically located block by import_array()